# Using function with multiple args over a list

Tags: gap

So working in GAP, I have constructed a list, $L$,  of the normal subgroups of a given group of interest (which I defined to be $G$). Now I want to construct a new list $Q$ which is to be comprised of the corresponding quotient groups $G/N$ given by the command FactorGroup(G,N) for each $N\in L$, and herein lies the problem. There is a nice way to do this for functions of a single argument:

gap> Q:=List(L,FunctionOfOneVar);

Where FunctionOfOneVar is any function w/ a single argument, and GAP will do exactly what I am wanting it do for this case, but the problem is, FactorGroup takes two arguments, one of which I want to always be $G$, the other running over the list $L$. Is there a nice way to do this for a function of several vars? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone else having issues with similar tasks, I figured it out:

You use the command ListX, and you must make the other vars (that aren't to run over a list) into lists, with [var]. So for the case at hand, I did:

gap> Q:=ListX([G],L,FactorGroup);

and voila, I had my new list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
List(L, N -> FactorGroup(G, N));
```

since one of the two arguments to the function is fixed.

Comment: I think I actually tried that one and it didn't work, but maybe I had the syntax wrong...either way, I found a solution that was similarly efficient (and actually more general).

Comment: This does work, why not share your solution too?

Comment: I already have. :)

Comment: Right! Didn't spot that!